# How to upload my dataset into Google Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have my dataset on my *local device*. Is there any way to upload this dataset into google colab directly.

**Note:**

I tried this code :

```
from google.colab import files
uploaded = files.upload()
```

But it loads file by file. I want to upload the whole dataset directly

Answer (score 9):

Here's the workflow I used to upload a zip file and create a local data directory:

1. zip the file locally. Something like: `$zip -r data.zip data`
2. upload zip file of your data directory to colab using their (Google's) instructions.

```py
from google.colab import files

uploaded = files.upload()
```

3. Once zip file is uploaded, perform the following operations:

```py
import zipfile
import io

zf = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(uploaded['data.zip']), "r")
zf.extractall()
```

Your data directory should now be in colab's working directory under a 'data' directory.

Comment: is there a more permanent way to store the data? can't I keep the dataset on my drive and have colab read it into memory? (process the files on my drive into a model, etc.)

Comment: [This tutorial](https://medium.com/deep-learning-turkey/google-colab-free-gpu-tutorial-e113627b9f5d) has more information about mounting your google drive and naming it locally as "Drive" to access content in your drive account.

Answer (score 1):

Zip or tar the files first, and then use [tarfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) or [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) to unpack them.

Comment: You can also use `!unzip`, instead of python's `zipfile.ZipFile`

Comment: if my understanding is correct. I know that if I want to upload anything to colab, firstly I should upload it on my google drive. then after mounting google drive with colab. this will upload it on colab.
is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to store all the dataset into a numpy object and upload to drive. There you can easily retrieve it. (zipping and unzipping also fine but I faced difficulty with it)